# How do I check if a number is a permutation of another number?

Tags: r, permutation

I would like to check if a number is a permutation of another number. An ideal function would look like

```
isperm(14,41) 

TRUE
```

Comment: What do you mean by permutation of a number?

Comment: @RonakShah that both numbers contain exactly the same digits, in a different order

Comment: This function sounds like an Apple biotech product...

Comment: Haha @geryan up vote!

Comment: knew somebody would make a joke out of it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Convert to string, split into sep char, compare array

```
isperm <- function(x,y){
    all(sort(strsplit(as.character(x),"")[[1]]) == sort(strsplit(as.character(y),"")[[1]]) )
}
```

Comment: thank you. I understand the function very well although I'm a little confused about what the [[1]] is doing for both x and y

Comment: strsplit returns a list of length 1. [[1]] converts it into character vector. Try and discover :)

Comment: aha! I see now. Right because I get an array from strsplit, then you just select its first and only member. Makes sense